# Custom Field Filter by Role - Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom field and selected "Filter by role" to "Subscriber" and assigned the custom field to the post type. Now when I add a new post and assigned the subscriber (ie: created a Test Post and assigned the subscriber to "grade 1") after I click on the update again I changed the subscriber "grade 1" to "grade 2", after that when I viewed the page by login as grade 1 that particular post is viewed. This Happens only if I edit the post and change the subscriber again.

```
$args_events = array(
    'post_type' => 'parents_login',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $page_num,
    'posts_per_page' => CUSTOM_ROWS_PER_PAGE,
    'cat' => get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'select_grade',
            'value' => $current_user->ID,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args_events = array(
        'post_type' => 'parents_login',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => CUSTOM_ROWS_PER_PAGE,
        'cat' => get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) ),
        'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'select_grade',
               'value' => serialize( strval( $current_user->ID ) ),
               'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
         ),
);
```

Using this I attained result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change OR to AND

Where is your $current_user; variable?

I see it in your code, but not the value that it has.

Please update code